# Create Customization panel for Plugins not for theme

Tags: plugin-development, customization

I have enough experience to create customization panel to WordPress themes. But I don't any idea to create customization panel for WordPress plugins!

We go to theme customization panel from **Dashboard> Customize Your Site** If I want to create the Customization panel to my plugin, How can go to the customizer plugin panel? Did also I can go to plugin and theme customization panel together from **Dashboard> Customize Your Site** or must create another button or subpage to plugin customization that different from theme customization?

Comment: There’s no difference between theme or plugin customisation. You add panels exactly the same way.

Comment: Ok but we know from Dashboard> Customize Your Site go to theme customization panel, Do you mean also from Dashboard> Customize Your Site also go to plugin customization panel? Does this not cause conflict between theme and plugin customization panel?

Comment: There is no plugin customisation panel and theme customisation panel. There’s just *the* Customiser and plugins and themes can add controls to it.